# What is the difference between linker option libssl.a and -lssl in cmake?

Tags: c, cmake, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I was going to link a program statically with `libcurl`, `libssl`, `libcryto`. Then I found this behaviour.

If i link with `-lssl`, `ldd` shows that compiled binary depends on `libssl.so` shared object.

But if i link with `libssl.a`, `ldd` shows that compiled binary doesn't depends on that (This is what i wants).

The case is similar for `libssl` and `libcrypto` but not for `libcurl`.

I always thought/read before those are same(link options `-lssl` and `libcurl.a`). Can you please put some light on this or any tutorial about this?

Comment: `libssl.a` is the static library, while `libssl.so` is the dynamic library. When you use `libssl.a` you *explicitly* link with that library. When you use the `-l` option the linker will decide which library to use (if multiple variants are available).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my whole life is a lie :(
Thanks a lot.

Comment: The question isn't really duplicate, but the answer is "read some general information about static/dynamic libraries", so I closed this as duplicate pointing to a question rich of relevant information.